# Kendo Grid Decimal Column Sorting

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I want sort the kendo grid column. In the below screen shot i need sort the WBS column either ascending or descending. In that column have that values like 1.1, 1.1.1, 1.2.1, 1.2.1.1, 1.2.1.2, 1.3, 2, 2.1, 2.1.1, 2.2 etc., [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to define an ad-hoc `compare` function for `WBS` column. This is possible using [`columns.sortable.compare`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns-sortable-compare).

Now, the question is *inventing* a function that is able to compare two values as you need.

It comes to my mind doing the following:

1. Split the original value separated by "." in an array of values. Ex: `"10.1.2"` becomes `[ "10", "1", "2" ]`.
2. Compare one by one the values of the arrays keeping in mind that one might be shorter than the other which means that is smaller (i.e. `10.1` is smaller `10.1.1`).

This would be something like:

```
columns   : [
    ...
    { 
        field: "wbs", 
        width: 150, 
        title: "WBS",
        sortable: {
            compare: function (a, b) {
                var wbs1 = a.wbs.split(".");
                var wbs2 = b.wbs.split(".");
                var idx = 0;
                while (wbs1.length > idx && wbs2.length > idx) {
                    if (+wbs1[idx] > +wbs2[idx]) return true;
                    if (+wbs1[idx] < +wbs2[idx]) return false;
                    idx++;
                }
                return (wbs1.length > wbs2.length);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
]
```

**NOTE**: As I said before and as result of the `split`, what I get in the arrays are `strings`. So it is pretty important that we use a *little trick* for comparing the values as `number` that is prepend a `+`. So when I do `if (+wbs1[idx] > +wbs2[idx])` I'm actually comparing the values on `wbs1[idx]` and `wbs2[idx]` as numbers.

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/H4U7D/2/

Comment: Hi OnaBai. Thanks for your reply. But the WBS column is not sorting in your jsfiddle link. can you please check and advice me.

Comment: It works on my browser. Did you click on the header for sorting it ?

Comment: It's working in chrome. But it does not support in IE11.

Comment: I've updated Kendo UI to a more recent version (v2014.1.318). Do you mind trying it in http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/H4U7D/3/ in IE11?

Comment: Onabai, do you know how we can implement your solution in Kendo UI for ASP MVC?